# Bazel build command ambiguous stdout/stderr while piped

Tags: pipe, bazel, io-redirection

In a typical Bazel project, running `bazel build :main`, for example, causes this output in the **terminal**:

```
Analyzing: target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
    currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
    Fetching @rules_cc; fetching 5s
```

But when it's piped to a file (`bazel build :main 2>output.txt`), the content of `output.txt` is similar to:

```
Analyzing: target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //:main (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

It is also what I see in the gitlab CI frontend. (Since it has piped the output of the command...).
I've got two questions:
  **1.** How can I capture the details of Analyzing; like what is being fetched now? (i.e. how to capture the exact same outputs?)
  **2.** What does `0 packages loaded` mean? What about *configuring* a target?

Comment: Any idea about the 2nd question? What does `configuring` mean in Bazel?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this does everything you care about, but I would approach this using the [Build Event Protocol](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-event-protocol.html), which will either write out a file (see `--build_event_binary_file` and `--build_event_text_file`) describing all the actions that were taken by Bazel, or it will open a gRPC connection to a server of your choosing (see `--bes_backend`) and emit the events there. Trying to parse the stdout/err of the binary definitely doesn't contain all the information you desire.

If there are things missing from the BEP output, I would file a bug against Bazel and ask if they'll add an event for it.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm going to try it. I'll come back soon with the result. Thanks.

Comment: I tried that. Some good info. But still, I don't see what was fetching? (I expect the URLs or something like that.

Comment: If you think there is more information that should be included in the BEP output, I think filing an [issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new) to have it added is probably the best course of action. If you could comment on here with a link to your issue I would love to follow along

Comment: Thanks. I issued that: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10343

Comment: Any idea about the 2nd question? What does `configuring` mean in Bazel?